# Taking picture and geotag it

Tags: android, android-intent

I should make an app to take a picture and geotag it. I see 2 ways to do it:

1. Using an intent for the android camera default, take the picture (meanwhile looking for GPS location), and then edit EXIF header;
2. Build a camera application through the camera API, then geotag it with `setGpsLatitude()` etc.

I'd like to know which is the best choice, or generally when is better using first or the second way.

Comment: Doesn't your default camera already geotag your photos?

Answer (score 5):

I would use an intent to the camera and then geo tag it. Check out this documentation for the gps side of things. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Just as an FYI if you want the gps to be super accurate it is not a pleasure to work with. Especially if the user is in a basement somewhere.

From my knowledge there are two main routes for gps. Fine gps and network. Network uses triangulation of service towers to tie down a gps corrd. Not super accurate but it works. Fine works but can take up to 15 seconds if the user is in a bad spot.

You also could use the google maps api and allow the user to enter in an address of where the photo was taken and convert that address to a lat and lng. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Cheers,

Jake

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Using intent was my first choice (can use all camera features without re-implementing them in a customized version, which is not needed for the moment).
Considering the pic will be (probably) sent over Internet, I was thinking using both GPS-PROVIDER and NETWORK-PROVIDER, starting them before launching intent (so that it can catch location meanwhile user takes the pic). Is it a good/bad idea? App will be used on open area, so there shouldn't be big problems on obtaining location

Comment: Yeah I would do anything I could to save time capturing there location. So yes that is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

check android camera app source,

> get geo location:
>   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git/+/android-4.4.2_r2/src/com/android/camera/LocationManager.java
>
> geo tag:
>   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git/+/android-4.4.2_r2/src/com/android/camera/Storage.java